# Automate Authentication to Azure as Service Principal using Windows Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I need to use Powershell for some automated Jenkins jobs. To do the work, I need to authenticate as a Service Principal in a non-interactive fashion.

With the Azure CLI, this can be accomplished non-interactively using the following command:

```
az login --service-principal -u "$client_id" -p "$client_secret" -t "$tenant_id"
```

However, accomplishing this using the `Connect-AzAccount` cmdlet for Powershell is proving to be tough. Is there anyway to achieve the same result as above using a Powershell cmdlet? All of the options [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-1.6.0#examples) seem to be interactive only.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `Connect-AzAccount` to login non-interactively, try the command as below, the `strong password` is your client secret, it works fine on my side.

```
$azureAplicationId ="Azure AD Application Id"
$azureTenantId= "Your Tenant Id"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "strong password" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to store the password somewhere in vault instead saving it local , as i don't want to save the password in my local machine to login azure