# Powershell script to copy files from server to azure blob container

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting

I want to copy all the files in my server(azure vm) to a container (azure blob storage) is it possible through powershell?
I'm new to powershell please help me out
In any script with you please share

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you have installed the [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-1.7.0) powershell module in your VM and the place you want to run the command. In my sample, I use my PC to run the command.

Try to store the script below in the PC, I use `C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\script.ps1`, the script will upload all the files in the folder `C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test` in your VM, you can change it to the path what you want.

*script.ps1*:

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<StorageAccountName>" -StorageAccountKey "<StorageAccountKey>"
$files = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test" -recurse).FullName
foreach($file in $files){
    Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $context -File "$file" -Container "<container name>" -Blob "$file" 
}
```

Then run the command:

```
Connect-AzAccount
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName 'rgname' -Name 'vmname' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath 'C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\script.ps1'
```

If you want to login with non-interactive way, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582300/automate-authentication-to-azure-as-service-principal-using-windows-powershell/55583672#55583672).

Change the parameters to what you want, after uploading the file to the container, it will appear like the original file structure.