# Use powershell script to copy files from Azure VM to designated folder in the container of Azure Blob Storage

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

I read the following link for copying files from VM to the azure blob storage account. However, if i need to copy it to designated folder in the container, say, containerName/UserA/Report/A and containerName/UserA/Report/B according to the file name in VM.What will be the command look like? Thanks for your help.

[Powershell script to copy files from server to azure blob container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643403/powershell-script-to-copy-files-from-server-to-azure-blob-container)

Answer (score 1):

You can prepend the desired path to the file name to set the name of the blob. Something like:

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<StorageAccountName>" -StorageAccountKey "<StorageAccountKey>"
$files = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test" -recurse).FullName
foreach($file in $files){
    $blobName = "UserA/Report/$file"
    Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $context -File "$file" -Container "<container name>" -Blob $blobName 
}
```

Comment: If I use managed identity (azcopy login —identity), how to use the set-azstorageblobcontent function to copy the file from vm. Thanks

Comment: Please do not ask additional questions in comments. Post a separate question for this. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the code, I found that the $file actually contain the full path say c:/folder1/folderb/file.doc, so the blob name will become /usera/report/c:/folder1/folderb/file.doc.

Comment: You would want to extract the file name from the path in this case.